# Quick Live Latex Display

Tags: latex, desktop-apps

I am a maths teacher and have to teach my students over video in this lock down. Now all I want for them is to view expression and equations. I aim to achieve this by sharing my screen and using some sort of LaTex editor that is able to display the results on the go. I know there are some online tools. But is there any such application native to linux. I do not wish to build complex documents using this editor. Just some sort of split view where my latex will turn into expressions live as I type or after each statement.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. There are plenty LaTeX editors and displayers native to Ubuntu. Do you mean to say that you are familiar with LaTeX in Windows, but not under Ubuntu? Or are you asking for an alternative to LaTeX, like LibreOffice? Please edit and update your question.

Comment: See https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-latex-editor-top-33-reviewed-for-linux-nerds/

Comment: [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) may work for you.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the list. I ended up using one of the editors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the closest to that wysiwyg that you want is Lyx. Check it out, in youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiDFyIuloy4

you find some tutorial so you can get the feeling of it. I am using a drawing app (Miro) for maths in a "whiteboard" in android, I share that app from my tablet and use the PC for audio and presentations.

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggesting Lyx. But while generating preview, it had some error with pdftex.dex. I was not specially looking for wysiwyg but Lyx would have been nice. I ended up using Gummi. Also thanks for the Miro suggestion, would definitely look into that. I think this answer might also help other who might be looking for such recommendations. So I am going to select this as the answer. Thanks all for your help